# How can I create an array in C without knowing the length beforehand? I can't assume the system will be using any specific standard

Tags: c, arrays

I tried doing something like:

```
int z = 1;
int *p = &z;
*(++p) = 2;
printf("%d",*p);
```

I would assume *p=22 and *(p-1)=1 but the code will compile and when I try to print it, it crashes. I will know the length at runtime, it's a user input.

Thank you.

Comment: Look into `malloc`.

Comment: That's what you use dynamic memory allocation for.

Comment: Get a C textbook.

Comment: You should never try to mess with stack allocated memory outside of your stack frame, in C if you were to declare and initialize a variable in a function, say `int z = 1` the memory for that is fixed and allocated straight after the function is invoked. Have a look into dynamically allocated memory in C.

Comment: If you cannot assume any reasonable standard past ANSI C, you should at least read the second edition of K&R's book "The C Programming Language", which goes into how to implement a `malloc` function to allocate memory to pointers at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

`z` is a scalar.

`int *p = &z;` is valid. `++p` is also valid as you are allowed to point one-past the address of a scalar.

But the behaviour on your dereferencing that pointer (with `*(++p)`) is *undefined*.

Consider using a *variable length array* (C99 onwards although even a C11 standard-compliant compiler can choose not to implement variable length arrays). Failing that, use `malloc` which has been part of the C standard since at least 1978.

Comment: Note that variable length arrays are only supported from C99 onwards

Comment: @Cantfindname C99 is a 17 years old standard, even C11 is already 5 years old.

Comment: @mch But OP said "I can't assume the system will be using any specific standard". OP might need to use some crappy Microsoft C compiler or something.

Comment: Not to mention that C11 says that "Variable length arrays are a conditional feature that implementations need not support".

Answer (score 1):

You would use `malloc` and `realloc` to allocate and reallocate memory to pointers, to create arrays at runtime.

Note that de-referencing memory you haven't allocated -- i.e., space "outside" your runtime array -- is undefined behaviour that can cause crashes or other problems. Don't do it.